# Resetting and updating a list property in polymer 1.0.rc

Tags: dart, polymer-1.0, dart-polymer

I have a List of Map items property.

```
@property 
List<Map<String, dynamic>> items = [
    {'name': 'Acrid', 'checked': false},
    {'name': 'Fishy', 'checked': false}
  ];
```

that are displayed when an if condition evaluates to true.

```
<template
    restamp
    is = "dom-if"
    if = "[[normalChangedRestampedToggler]]">
  <div
      class = "layout horizontal wrap body auto"
      id = "container">

    <paper-material
        pad-bottom
        class = "dropdown-content layout vertical"
        elevation = "5">

      <paper-input
          value = "{{filterValue}}"
          label = "Search"
          class = "margin">
        <iron-icon
            suffix
            icon = "search"></iron-icon>
      </paper-input>

      <paper-menu multi
                  on-click = "onClickHandler">
        <template
            id = "repeat"
            is = "dom-repeat"
            items = "{{items}}"
            filter = "{{filter(filterValue)}}">
          <paper-item
              role = "menuitemcheckbox"
              toggles = "true"
              active = "{{item.checked}}">
            <paper-checkbox
                checked = "[[item.checked]]"
                checked-changed = "checkedChanged"></paper-checkbox>
            [[label(item)]]
          </paper-item>
        </template>
      </paper-menu>

    </paper-material>
  </div>
</template>
```

The conditional if is set by a paper-toggle button:

```
  @reflectable
  void toggleNormalChangedEvent( event, [_] ) {
    normalChangedRestampedToggler = !normalChangedRestampedToggler;
    set('normalChangedRestampedToggler', normalChangedRestampedToggler);

    switch ( normalChangedRestampedToggler ) {
      case false:
        for(var item in data)
        {
          item['checked'] = false;
        }
        set('items', data);
        data = new List<Map<String, dynamic>>( );
        break;
    }
  }
```

While the UI toggles as expected, the

```
set('items', data);
```

does not seem to reset the items - the old checked state of the checkboxes still remain. It appears that the items property does not update.

Can this update be forced by some means?

PS Could the problem be due to the fact that the checkboxes are in a nested-template? If so, is there a way to overcome this problem?

Thanks

Comment: That's a lot of code!  Can you try to create a minimal example - remove as much code as possible while keeping the issue reproducible. This is a good practice and often reveals the problem already.

Comment: I have created a small project that generates the same error. However it is  almost the same as above. I wish there was a way I could post a folder here or some other option.

Comment: Please see edited code above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is redundant

```
normalChangedRestampedToggler = !normalChangedRestampedToggler;
```

because this includes the above (added `!`)

```
set('normalChangedRestampedToggler',! normalChangedRestampedToggler);
```

---

```
for(var item in data) {
  item['checked'] = false;
}
```

should be

```
for(int i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  set('items.$i.checked', false);
}
```

---

```
data = new List<Map<String, dynamic>>( );
```

doesn't do anything because you probably assign the same list again and Polymer recognizes that there is no change.

Also `template is="dom-repeat` uses

```
items = "{{items}}"
```

why do you set `data`?

Comment: The redundancy was for my own proofing. Understood. Replacing `item['checked']` with `'item.checked'` I don't understand. If I use the suggestion I get the following error `Class '_InternalLinkedHashMap' has no instance setter 'checked='.

NoSuchMethodError: method not found: 'checked='
Receiver: _LinkedHashMap len:2
Arguments: [false]`. The resetting of `data` is necessary so the old selections are overritten. Still, the checkboxes in the template are not reset.

Comment: Worked! The new for was the solution. However, `data' should be replaced with `items'. I see a yellow highlighted formatted code in some comments. What is markup for that?

Comment: `>` as first character of the line (ensure there is a blank line before and after such text). There is also the `"` (blockquote) button in the editor toolbar which adds the `>` at the beginning of each line of the selected text. I changed my answer, I hope this is what you meant in your last comment (`items` <--> `data`)

Comment: The change is correct. Just add a closing quote to  'items.$i.checked in the for set('items.$i.checked, false);